# Servlet parameters and doPut

Tags: java, rest, servlets

Trying to get parameters from a PUT request using HttpServlet#doPut:

```
public void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    // name is null
}
```

Using curl to send the request:

```
curl  -X PUT \
      --data "name=batman" \
      --header "Content-Type: text/plain" http://localhost:8080/sample.html
```

works fine with using doGet and GET curl request.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Based on comments and further research I realized that the Servlet cannot assume anything about the data being put onto the server and therefore, will not parse name/value pairs.

The following solution seems to be the proper way to handle any data passed via PUT, and can be parsed as XML, Name/Value, or whatever.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream());

String data = br.readLine();
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem: i'm trying to implement a restfull service, PUT is meant to replace the resource. Jetty makes all data available in the request parameters map, tomcat however doesn't..

Comment: According to Java Web Services: Up and Running, "doPost and doPut differ significantly because the servlet containers runtime does not generate a usable parameter map. (This is the case in both Tomcat and Jetty)"

Answer (score 6):

Unlike in `doGet()` and `doPost()` methods, we are not able to get the request parameters using the `getParameter()` method in `doPut()` and `doDelete()` methods. We need to retrieve them manually from the input stream.

The following method retrieves request parameters and returns them in a map:

```
public static Map<String, String> getParameterMap(HttpServletRequest request) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    Map<String, String> dataMap = null;

    try {

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
                request.getInputStream());
        br = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String data = br.readLine();

        dataMap = Splitter.on('&')
                .trimResults()
                .withKeyValueSeparator(
                        Splitter.on('=')
                        .limit(2)
                        .trimResults())
                .split(data);

        return dataMap;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    return dataMap;
}
```

The example uses Google's Guava library to parse the parameters.
For a complete example containing `doGet()`, `doPost()`, `doPut()` and `doDelete()` methods, you can read my [Using jsGrid tutorial](http://zetcode.com/articles/jsgridservlet/).

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by `doPut()` is not working? As far as I know, it doesn't work like `doGet()` or `doPost()`, where you have request parameters and stuff.

PUT can be used to put something on the server. In particular, the PUT operation allows a client to place a file on the server and is similar to sending a file by FTP. Check out this example, I found on JGuru.

```
->GET /file.dat HTTP/1.1

<-HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

->PUT /file.dat HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello!

<-HTTP/1.1 200 OK

->GET /file.dat HTTP/1.1

<-HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello!
```