# Getting parameters from PUT HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, servlets, put

I have an HttpServlet that is trying to handle a PUT request, that has some form parameters  (sent with a "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header). I have the same setup working fine for POST, but for some reason a PUT request turns up emptywhen I ask for the parameters:

```
protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws {
   Map<String,String[]> params = req.getParameterMap();
   System.out.println(params.size());
}
```

the size of params is 0 even though I am passing parameters in.

Is there some other way to read params for a PUT request?

Comment: How are doing the PUT from client? Are you using HTML Form and submitting with method="PUT"?

Comment: no, I've used a GUI client that I use for testing, as well as just simple CURL command

Comment: @Nathan can you post the command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the the following SO question, seems to answer your question:

[Servlet parameters and doPut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855835/servlet-parameters-and-doput)

Comment: Thanks, the method from that question definitely works - if I print out the inputStream I see all of the params I'm passing in.

Any idea why grabbing the parameterMap wouldn't work? Is there something aside from setting the content type that I need to do for a PUT request?

Comment: I am not sure, but I am guessing it is because of the semantics of the PUT method i.e. as per the spec, The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload so I guess the Content-Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" doesn't really make sense w.r.t PUT method.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put them on the URL as arguments. The body of a PUT doesn't have the semantics of a POST, which interprets it as form arguments.

Comment: This seems to be the case from my experience.

Comment: @PhilipRego That *is* the case, from the RFC.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC provides FormContentFilter to parse form data for PUT,PATCH and DELETE and expose it as servlet request parameter

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadocapi/org/springframework/web/filter/FormContentFilter.html