# How to get parameter from a PUT request?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, tomcat6

I am trying to send a JSON array from browser to a Java Servlet on PUT method.

My ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
  url : "./manageShoppingCart",
  data : {
    jsonArray : JSON.stringify(itemsArray)
  },
  type : 'PUT',
  contentType : 'application/json'
}).done(function(rsp) {
  console.log("done" + rsp);
}).fail(function(err) {
  console.log("fail" + err);
});
```

An on server is (in the doPut method):

```
    String jsonArray = request.getParameter("jsonArray"); // this is null
    // but if I read from request stream I get the data
    ServletInputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();

    String string = convertStreamToString(inputStream); 
    System.out.println(string); // jsonArray=%5B%7B%22itemId%22%3A%228003%22%2C%22itemQuantity%22%3A%2210%22%7D%2C%7B%22itemId%22%3A%228004%22%2C%22itemQuantity%22%3A%222%22%7D%5D
```

The interesting part is that if change the method and send as POST I get get the parameter correctly.

My guess is that Tomcat 6 needs some settings to get a parameter through PUT (url encoded.. etc).

So, what should I do to send correctly JSON array through PUT method?

**UPDATE**:
I am not sure if this is the right way to do it, but for me I find it easy to write myself a converter from message to parameter:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;

public class RequestsService {

public static String getDecodedMessage(ServletInputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String bodyMessageEncoded;

    bodyMessageEncoded = bf.readLine();
    String message = URLDecoder.decode(bodyMessageEncoded, "UTF-8");
    return message;

}

public static String getParameter(String url, String paramName) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(paramName + "=[^&]*"); // regex for "paramName='anything unless is &'"
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
    matcher.find();
    String value = matcher.group().split("=")[1];
    return value;
}

public static String getParameterFromStream(ServletInputStream inputStream, String paramName) throws IOException {
    String decodedMessage = getDecodedMessage(inputStream);
    return getParameter(decodedMessage, paramName);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not wrong HTTP PUT is meant to put a resource in the given URI, so the server should take the body of the command and "store" it. If the server receives a GET request with the same URI, those data should be returned. See [Servlet parameters and doPut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855835/servlet-parameters-and-doput) for more details.

I would try something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url : "./manageShoppingCart",
  data : JSON.stringify(itemsArray), //just the data, no parameter name
  type : 'PUT',
  contentType : 'application/json'
}).done(function(rsp) {
  console.log("done" + rsp);
}).fail(function(err) {
  console.log("fail" + err);
});
```

And then just get the data in the body and parse it as a JSON Object in the server side:

```
ServletInputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
String string = convertStreamToString(inputStream); 
JSONObject jsonArray= new JSONObject(string); //Maybe a JSONArray suits better here
```