# Easy way to get PUT data in JSP?

Tags: jsp, rest, put

I'm looking for the easiest way to get PUT data on a JSP page. Something equivelant to

```
String something = request.getParameter("param");
```

I can't find anything about it on the internet because put is too common of word, or it's not done very often.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Servlet parameters and doPut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855835/servlet-parameters-and-doput)

Comment: Are you talking about getting query parameters in JSP? If yes then try using JSP JSTL Tags & JSP EL for eg. `${param['param']}` or `<c:out value="${param['param']}"/>`

Comment: There is no parameter with PUT, first comment answered my question though.